# PHP "Global" include

Tags: php

Ohai,
I'm writing a small PHP application, using a separated config.php file and a functions.php, containing all my custom functions, I'll use in the application. Now, do I really have to include the config.php in every function or is there a way to include the config for all functions in the file in one step?

Thanks.

Comment: @pavium "ohayo" i think ("hello" on japanese)

Comment: @pavium, Ohai http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_T540VS6x-Ok/SagwspTbFUI/AAAAAAAAACg/7zmTeKpFL3I/S1600-R/ohai.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are bound to use require, require_once, include or include_once when you are to reach methods and classes inside other php files, unless you use some sort of framework.

Try to build a global file which has all includes in it, that way thats the only file you have to include.

Comment: Additional read could be the [MVC model](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html).

Answer (score 2):

The very standard way to do it is include it from your index.php file. Your index.php should include your other pages like :

```
include 'config.php';
include 'functions.php';
$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 'home';

switch($page)
{
    case 'home':           break;
    case 'mail':           break;
    case 'contact':        break;
    default:
        $page = 'home';
}

include("$page.php");
```

Therefore, at index.php you can include any pages you want.

Comment: i regularly would not say anything, but why downvote :? This is pretty standard, which i actually pasted from one of my projects :/

Comment: Can't be sure why people do this ... I assumed it was because the question didn't mention *index.php*

Comment: i got -1 about 5 seconds after posting, so you can imagine :P

Comment: I didn't vote, but I have an offtopic question - where did you learn about those standard ways? I'm curious because I'm new to PHP and your code looks nice to me.

Comment: I don't really remember where i first read that, but i've been doing some things for years. This is a technique i use all the time to include files and prevent file inclusion attacks as well(it's secure code to have the switch to check - must be there). Then, i would have a controller that handles a model's logic, pretty much an MVC model. In short, the controller would be something like profile.php, the model would be profile.class.php and the views would be a (custom and fast) template system.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `global.php` containing all your `require` (or `include`) statements and simply include that file.

Answer (score 1):

convert your functions to methods of a class and you'll never look back.

```
<?php 
 class MyClass { 
   var $config;     

   function __construct($config) {
     $this->config = $config;
   }

   function myFunc($myArg) {
     return $myArg * $this->config['someSetting'];
   }
}
```

regards,

/t

Comment: Agree, still needs to be included though

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/auto_prepend_file) in the `php.ini` for laziness. Or via .htaccess:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /home/www/host1235/htdocs/lib/config.php
```

But that's really an option if your application is coherent, all scripts require that very config file. Otherwise this option needs to be unset again per directory.